# Smooth Hilbert structure on Frechet manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

A theorem of Henderson states that every infinite dimensional, separable, metric Frechet manifold F has a unique structure of a smooth Hilbert manifold. Let us denote it by F'.

Can one characterize the smooth maps from a Hilbert manifold U to  F', in particular in the case F is the smooth mapping space between (finite dimensional) smooth manifolds, $C^{\infty}(M,N)$, where M is closed.

Comment: What do you mean by "characterize"?

Comment: Maybe distinguish is more appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: Henderson's theorem gives only a topological embedding of $F$ as an open subset of a Hilbert space, not a **smooth** embedding, right? The Hilbert manifold structure $F'$ is then determined by the underlying homeomorphism type of $F$, so the two **smooth** structures $F$ and $F'$ might be 'smoothly' quite unrelated... Are you asking whether they in fact are related in some way, e.g. by looking at smooth maps from another Hilbert space? Note that a map from $U$ might be smooth as a map to $F'$ but not smooth as a map to $F$ and vice versa. (I'm just trying to understand your question.)

Comment: @oldrich, Yes, this is what I mean. I wonder if you can say something in general, or maybe in the special case of the smooth mapping space you can expect some sort of adjunction.